# accessing local git repository from windows

Tags: windows, git, ubuntu, clone, gitosis

I have git repository (powered by gitosis) on my local ubuntu server

I want to have an access from the other local computer powered by windows xp (msysgit)

I have generated rsa key on windows machine and published to ubuntu server

I have .ssh/config file setted to use this key on windows machine

When I do

> ssh git@192.168.0.6

this works as desired, without password prompt

However when I try to clone repository with :

> git clone git@192.168.0.6:gitosis-admin

or

> git clone ssh://192.168.0.6/~/gitosis-admin

then I got following errors:

> fatal: 'gitosis-admin' does not appear to be git repository

When I try to clone with existing user account e.g. user named atom

> git clone atom@192.168.0.6:gitosis-admin

this works as desired, but does not work for other repo projects

My gitosis.conf:

> [gitosis]
>
> [group gitosis-admin]
>
> writable = gitosis-admin
>
> members = windows_user atom@atom-desktop
>
> [group team]
>
> writable = another_project
>
> members = @all

So my question is: 'Where is the problem ?' Should I change setting of gitdaemon ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this tutorial](http://translate.google.fr/translate?js=y&prev=_t&hl=fr&ie=UTF-8&layout=1&eotf=1&u=http://www.siteduzero.com/tutoriel-3-187504-heberger-des-depots-git-avec-gitosis.html&sl=fr&tl=en), git clone can be done even before starting tinkering with the `gitosis.conf` file.
So did you follow those steps?

> Firstly, it will have created a user called "git".
>   It has full power over the deposits, having in his home directory.

```
# Useradd-G git-d / home / git-s / bin / bash-m git
```

> Then we will get the SSH public key, and put in a temporary file as `/tmp/cle.pub`.
>   We will then, as root, run these commands:

```
sudo-H-u git gitosis-init < /tmp/cle.pub
```

> In this case, we'll run as git, but in addition, we will run into the home of the latter.
>   The `gitosis-init` command will initiate the filing by adding the user's public key as the deposit containing Committing configuration.
>
> If successful, you should get a result like this:

```
 Initialized empty Git repository in. /
 Initialized empty Git repository in. /
```

> (Yes, twice!)
>
> And if you view the contents of git home, like magic, it is full of files!
>
> Now we'll change the file permissions.
>   Indeed, I sometimes noticed it does not change because of rights problems.

```
sudo chmod 755 /home/git/repositories/gitosis-admin.gif/hooks/post-update
```

> This being done, I am pleased to announce that Git your server is ready, and it only remains to add your deposits and your users!
>
> Now all configuration is done on your computer via the deposit that we will import at once:

```
git clone git @ [server address]: gitosis-admin.gif
cd-gitosis admin.gif
```

Comment: I have done all things as you reported,

turned out that is better to access repo by full path for ssh git clone syntax e.g. git clone ssh://git@192.168.0.6/home/git/repositories/my_project

However to access repo without full path is better to add origin with server domain name e.g. git@atom-desktop instead of raw server address (e.g. 192. ...).
Anyway big thx for your time and response ,
 regards Tom